# How to add text into a div using a html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Adding the insertion of input type text into the div title on the same screen. Attempted broken function to they turn the input into a variable and use it to fill in the div.

```
<body>
<div class="form">
Form <br><br>
<form name="input" action="javascript:alert(titleValue);">

Title: <input type="text" name="title" class="titleInsert">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</div>

<div class="offer_display">

<div class="title" id= title></div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
var titleValue="";
$('#titleInsert').on("change", function () {
titleValue=$(this).val();
$("#title h3").text("titleValue");
});

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another problem with you code is, that you have to use "input" event and not "change".

**See working code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z037qv3n/**

```
<body>
   Form <br><br>
   <form name="input" action="javascript:alert(titleValue);">
   Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="titleInsert">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class="title" id="title"></div>
</body>

<script>
var titleValue="";
$('#titleInsert').on("input", function () {
  titleValue=$(this).val();
  $("#title").text(titleValue);
});

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code for `$('div.title').html(titleValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Live Demo : [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y0c7s2a/)

You have to include jQuery library in your head section like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

**There are lot of mistakes in your code please see below:**

First mistake you should put your jQuery inside ready function.

Second mistake there is no such id `#titleInsert` it is a class so you have to do `.titleInsert`

Third mistake there is no tag `h3` in `#title`

Fourth mistake you should use [.keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead `.change` event

Replace your jQuery code with following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var titleValue="";
$('.titleInsert').on("keyup", function () {
titleValue=$(this).val();
$("#title").text("titleValue");
});

});

</script>
```